# Run the methods in background which are in ViewModels in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin.iOS application. I want some part of my currently running features should also run in background. I have a `System.Timer` which is in the `App.cs(Load on start)` and added `TimerElapsed` event in one of the viewcontroller through which control passes to ViewModel on timer elapsed and executes all function.

Now I want the same feature should run in background also but unable to get thoughts how to achieve it. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: C# way: Create a new Thread or use Task.Run to alloc one from the thread pool, iOS way: Use a background queue and GCD. Or for timers, the "best" way  in C# (IMHO) is to use `System.Reactive` and you can in the background scheduler to run a timer subject and subscribe to the output (observable) on the ui thread.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But how can I do that? I have not worked on executing such background task before so if you can provide any examples it would be grateful.

Comment: Google/Bing `Task.Run` or `C# Thread`, there are many examples/tutorials on the web and Microsoft's site. If you are talking about running when your iOS App is sent to the "background", then go here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/

Comment: Do u mean background, when you send app background with home button?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be something like this

//Some async method

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
 // Code you want to run asynchronously 
 });
```

Goodluck!

In case of queries revert!

Answer (score 0):

Backround (**when you send your application to background with home button**) is a little bit complicated in IOS. You can achive in several ways

1) beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler but it has some limitation with time

2) locationUpdate event - but with timer it will work not very good. it more suteble when you need check something frome time to time

3) Make you app Player. Player can work even if it is in background

Im using method 3, and it works fine for me

You need add permission for background audio in plist file

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Then in your `AppDelegate` you need modify `FinishedLaunching` method

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ...
        var currentSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        currentSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers);
        currentSession.SetActive(true);
        ...

    }
```

And add next section, I also put it in `AppDelegat`

```
    #region Background Work

    private BackgroundTask _backgroundTask;

    private readonly Lazy<TouchLogger> _logger = new Lazy<TouchLogger>(() => new TouchLogger());

    public override  void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.DidEnterBackground(uiApplication);
        startBackgroundTask();
    }      


    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);

        if (_backgroundTask == null)
        {
            _backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(_logger.Value);
        }
        else if (_backgroundTask.IsRunned)
        {
            _backgroundTask.Stop();
            _logger.Value.Info("Background", "Task stopped");
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundTask()
    {
        _logger.Value.Info("Background", "startBackgroundTask() called");

        var needBackgroundActivity = true;// if you timer is running set true, if not false

        if (needBackgroundActivity)
        {
            if (_backgroundTask == null)
                _backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(_logger.Value);

            _backgroundTask.Start();

            _logger.Value.Info("Background", "Task runned");
        }
    }

    private class BackgroundTask
    {
        private const string EmptySoundFileName = "Sounds/empty";//wav file, I use 4 sec long file with no sound

        private TouchLogger _logger;

        private AVAudioPlayer _player;

        private NSTimer _debugTimer;

        public bool IsRunned { get; private set; }

        public BackgroundTask(TouchLogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            IsRunned = true;

            if (_player != null && _player.Playing)
            {
                Stop();
            }

            var bundle = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(EmptySoundFileName, "wav");
            var sound = new NSUrl(bundle);


            _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(sound);
            _player.NumberOfLoops = -1;
            _player.Volume = 0.1f;
            _player.PrepareToPlay();
            _player.Play();
            startDebugTimer();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunned = false;

            if (_player != null && _player.Playing)
            {
                _player.Stop();
                _player.Dispose();
                _player = null;
            }
            stopTimer(ref _debugTimer);
        }

        private void startDebugTimer()
        {
            initAndStartTimer(ref _debugTimer, 5,
                () => _logger.Value.Info("Background", "Background is fine!"));
        }

        private void initAndStartTimer(ref NSTimer timer, int intervalMin, Action action)
        {
            timer?.Invalidate();
            if (action != null)
                timer =
                    NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(
                        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalMin),
                        t => action());
        }



        private void stopTimer(ref NSTimer timer)
        {
            timer?.Invalidate();
            timer = null;
        }

    }

    #endregion
```

`TouchLogger` - send some messages to console, for checking background, you can remove it. Same with `_debugTimer`, it just write state of background worker avery 5 min.

If something not working tell me, i did it long time ago, so maybe missed something

Comment: I already had methods in one viewmodel and viewcontroller but the same now I want to run when app state enters in background also.

Comment: AppDelegate have DidEnterBackground so you need to put your logic there.

Comment: But still you will need to implement logic for backgroundTask. Other way, time will pass but elapse action wont be triggered. It will be triggerd only after you enter foregraund. It is specific of working in background on mobile devices. Then you are enter background all action stops for saving battery

Comment: Actually, I want the elapsed event to be fired in background when time elapse. Is there any approcah?

Comment: I have an application where I have already implemented the methods in ViewModels which run in active mode along with timer and it's elapsed event. Now requirement is that from that, couple of methods should also run in Background and need to use the same timer i.e. if time is elapsed in BackgroundMode only than elapsed event should be triggered and those methods should get executed. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Look if you want to handle you code in background, you need implement all logic from my answer.

Comment: If you need handle elapce action ONLY in background you can add next condition`UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Background`. Or add bool field in app delegat isBackground. when change it state in DidEnterBackground and WillEnterForeground  events